# Как правильно работать с методом fs.readdir() в Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Я писал бота для Discord на Node.JS (в VSCode) и столкнулся с ошибкой:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
>     at fs.readdir (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\GGBOT\ggame.js:11:25)
>     at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
> PS C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\GGBOT> node ggame.js
> { [Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\GGBOT\cmds\ping.js']
>   errno: -4052,
>   code: 'ENOTDIR',
>   syscall: 'scandir',
>   path: 'C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\GGBOT\\cmds\\ping.js' }
> C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\GGBOT\ggame.js:11
>     let jsfiles = f.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
> ```

Код:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const fs = require('fs');
let config = require('./botconfig.json');
let token = config.token;
let prefix = config.prefix;

fs.readdir("./cmds/ping.js", (err, files) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
  if (jsfiles.length <= 0) console.log("EEERRR (нету комманд)!!!");
  console.log(`Тебе доступно: ${jsfiles.length} строк комманд`)
  jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
    let props = require(`./cmds/${f}`);
    console.log(`${i + 1}.${f} Загружен!`);
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name,props);
  })    
})

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Включение! 1.. 2.. 3.. Бот ${bot.user.username} Включиился`);
  bot.generateInvite(["ADMINISTRATOR"]).then(link => {
    console.log(link)
  })
});

bot.on('message', msg => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.type == "dm") return;
  let user = message.author.username;
  let userid = message.author.id;
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let command = messageArray[0].toLoserCase();
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);
  if (message.content.startWith(prefix)) return;
  let cmd = bot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));
  if (cmd) cmd.run(bot,message,args);
})    

bot.login(token);
```

---

начиная с const Discord сам код

Answer (score 4):

Ты пытаешься получить листинг папки, обращаясь к файлу `ping.js`, и он тебе пишет, что это не папка.

В `fs.readdir()` поменяй путь `"./cmds/ping.js"` на `"./cmds"`:

```
fs.readdir("./cmds", (err, files) => { /* ... */ });
```